# Which caching proxy is the CDNs using?

Tags: proxy, cache

Is there any information about which caching proxies the famous CDNs are using?

Are they using OS proxies for caching or commercial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some use lighttpd or nginx.  Some use squid or varnish.

Get something like headerspy for Firefox, surf a few and check the headers that are returned.

Answer (score 3):

Akamai uses a modified version of Squid.

> **Akamai caches** (courtesy Neal Cardwell)
>
> The akamai machines at the edge are PCs running Linux and a slightly modified version of the squid cache. They are doing on-demand caching rather than push-based replication.

Source: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/ratul/akamai.html

Comment: Also, if you look at the Akamai debug response headers in the x-cache header you will see returns such as TCP_MEM_HIT which is a response code for the Squid Proxy Log Format.